# Windows 10 detects USB flash drives but not USB camera or smartphone

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, mtp

When I connect USB flash drives (simple storage drives), they are detected by Windows 10 without problem.

However, when I connect Android smartphones or cameras, the USB sound notification is heard, but the USB devices won't show up on file explorer.

I have tried these so far:

1. Since smartphones and cameras use MTP protocol, I installed MTP drivers for Windows 10, but problem persists.
2. Even updated the system bios! No luck.
3. Tried to update USB drivers, didn't help.
4. Played around with power options regarding USB, again no luck.

Can anybody help.

Comment: On your phone, you frequently need to go to the USB settings and specify that you want to enable MTP vs just using the USB port for charging only. Have you checked that the phone is allowing your PC to access its files?

Comment: @user1574981 Right, I have enabled MTP on phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operating system is Windows 10 **pro N** build 15063 (release 1703).  Looks like the **N** versions of Windows 10 lack something named Media Feature Pack.

[image: Windows 10 pro N]

I downloaded the proper version of Media Feature Pack [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817/media-feature-pack-for-n-edition-of-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017) for that specific build of Windows 10. If you download the wrong version, it won't install. There's a [nice list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions) for N versions of Windows 10 to choose from.

[image: installing Media Feature Pack]

After installing the proper version of Media Feature Pack, now Windows detects and shows content of smartphone.

Comment: Good find.  This version of the OS is rarely heard of in the US.